# How do we solve Lagrangian differential equations?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, coordinate-systems

Suppose I have a system $$L=\frac{1}{2}m(\dot{r}^2+r^2\dot{\theta}^2)-mgr\sin\theta$$ and my generalized coordinate system are polar coordinates. I come up with the Lagrangian equations with respect to the generalized coordinate $r$ and $\theta$ $$2m\dot{\theta}^2r-mg\sin\theta-m\ddot{r}=0,$$

$$-mgr\cos\theta-mr^2\ddot{\theta}=0,$$

where $\theta$ is the rotational argument, and $r$ is radial movement. The angular velocity of this system is constant. I want to solve this equation analytically, but I'm unsure about the relationship between the coordinates $r$ and $\theta$. These are generalized coordinates. This means they are both independent, so that the usual $x,y(x)$ relation does not exist.

I think these are both functions of time. To solve this equation for some $r(t)$, I have to treat $\theta$ as function of time as well. Then we would have two equations in two variables, correct?

Comment: Yes, correct, I think.

Comment: Correct. Be aware though, that non-linear ODEs are very difficult to solve in general. Also be aware that eliminating time and pursuing an implicit relation between $r$ and $\theta$ is a very powerful and useful technique sometimes.